# Closed cycle of area not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm struggling closing a plot. I've created a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{myContour.csv}
x,y
800,200
50,200
50,0
1000,0
1000,200
900,200
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{myContour.csv}{\myContour}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [fill=green] table [x={x}, y={y}] {\myContour};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above MWE yields the following figure:
[image: Open plot]

Now, I'd like to close the border, and adjust in the above code the plot statement as follows:

```
\addplot [fill=green] table [x={x}, y={y}] {\myContour} \closedcycle;
```

However, this yields an unexpected result:

[image: Closed plot]

My question is: How could I, without changing the external data, connect the last and first point of the area, properly closing it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-- cycle` at the end of the plot, i.e.

```
\addplot [fill=green] table [x={x}, y={y}] {\myContour} -- cycle;
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{myContour.csv}
x,y
800,200
50,200
50,0
1000,0
1000,200
900,200
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{myContour.csv}{\myContour}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [fill=green] table [x={x}, y={y}] {\myContour} -- cycle;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Perfect. I was not aware of the difference between \closedcycle and --cycle.